# Parámetro booleano return condicional

Tags: javascript

Mi pregunta es acerca de un  ejercicio y es el siguiente:
La función debe escoger entre escribir tres o dos parámetros según el cuarto parámetro sea true o false
si es true retornaría solo dos parámetros concatenados y si fuera false me pide retorne los tres parámetros concatenados:

llamando a la funcion de esta forma:

```js
cartel("Lic.", "Tomás", "Peralta", true)
"Lic. Peralta"
cartel("Ing.", "Dana", "Velázquez", false)
"Ing. Dana Velázquez"
```

la verdad que he estado intentando de varias formas la única que me daba el resultado esperado es esta que pongo a continuación pero me dice el instructor que debo  hayar el resultado llamando el resultado sin  crear comparaciones innecesarias.

```js
function cartel(titulo,nombre,apellido,tipo){
if(tipo==true){
  return titulo+" "+apellido
  }
  else{
    return titulo+" "+nombre+" "+apellido
    }
}
 cartel("Lic.", "Tomás", "Peralta", true)
```

Estuve trabajando con algunos ejercicios anteriores en los que la solución se obtenía por ejemplo:

```js
return cosa uno(da falso/verdadero)|| cosa dos (falso/verdadero)//segun el parametro
```

lastimosamente en este ejercicio no pude hallar la respuesta correcta, antes de escribir la solución, me gustaría me puedan ayudar dándome algunas pistas. De cualquier forma agradeceré la ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Una de las comparaciones innecesarias tiene que ver con el `if`. Revisa bien la sintaxis de la expresión: [if...else - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/if...else)

Comment: gracias, voy a hacerlo!

Comment: hola he revisado la sintaxis como lo aconsejaste, pero debido a mi inexperiencia no puedo encontrar la falla, pensé que podría ser la doble igualdad en el if, pero me sigue sin funcionar. Me puedes confirmar?

Comment: No era necesario el `== true` ya que `true == true`  devuelve `true` y `false == true` devuelve `false` es decir siempre devuelve `tipo` por lo que bastaba con `if(tipo)`

Comment: OK! esa es la respuesta que necesitaba, bueno al menos no estaba tan lejos! gracias.

Answer (score 1):

intenta algo como esto

```
return (($tipo) ? titulo+" "+apellido : titulo+" "+nombre+" "+apellido);
```

eso es un condicional terniario que te puede servir y en una sola linea.

Answer (score 0):

podrias reducirlo a una linea usando un ternario donde funciona

```
condicionBooleana ? verdadero : falso;
```

aplicándolo a tu ejemplo, tipo seria la condicion, en caso que sea verdadero en nombre ponemos "" , en caso que sea false ponemos el nombre con un espacio para separarlo del apellido:

```
function cartel(titulo,nombre,apellido,tipo){
 return titulo+" "+ (tipo ? "":nombre+" ") + apellido;
}
```

caso 2

```
function cartel(titulo,nombre,apellido,tipo){
   if(tipo){
     nombre = "";
   }
 return titulo+" "+nombre+" "+apellido
}
```

Comment: hola me funciono bien, una consulta habria otra posibilidad? de resolverlo a una linea sin usar el boleano ternario, me parece una solución que no iba a poder imaginar  o pensar siguiendo el progreso del curso ya que nunca la habíamos visto hasta ahora. Gracias

Comment: Podrias consultar como venias haciendo el IF sobre tema en caso que sea tu bool true a la variable nombre la seteas con ""; y en el return.- ve la respuesta como quedaria.

Answer (score 0):

Según el enunciado:

> La función debe escoger entre escribir tres o dos parámetros según el
>   cuarto parámetro sea true o false

Sería oportuno (o tal vez no mucho) preguntarle al instructor qué pasa si el último parámetro no es un booleano. Probablemente lo que él quiera sea tratar `tipo` forzándolo a un booleano de manera que un string no vacío sea `true` y un cero sea `false`, por ejemplo.

Si ese es el caso, yo lo haría como sigue:

```js
function cartel (titulo, nombre, apellido, tipo){
  var resultado=[titulo];

  if(!tipo){
     resultado.push(nombre);
  }

  resultado.push(apellido);
  return resultado.join(" ");
}

console.log(cartel("Lic.", "Tomás", "Peralta", true));

console.log(cartel("Lic.", "Tomás", "Peralta", false));
```

Answer (score -1):

No sé si tu profesor se referirá a esto, pero es redundante (y muy típico de los novatos, todos hemos pasado por ahí), comparar booleanos:

```
if ( a === true) ... if (b === false) ...
```

se puede reducir a

```
if (a) ... if (!b) ...
```

Y lo mismo pasa con los `else` tras un `return`:

```
if (a) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

Se puede dejar como:

```
if (a) {
  return 1;
}
return 0;
```

o incluso como:

```
return a? 1: 0;
```

Por tanto tu función se puede quedar como:

```
function cartel(titulo,nombre,apellido,tipo){
  if(tipo){
    return titulo+" "+apellido;
  }
  return titulo+" "+nombre+" "+apellido;
}
```

O simplificando aún más:

```
function cartel(titulo,nombre,apellido,tipo){
  return tipo ? (titulo+' '+apellido): (titulo+' '+nombre+' '+apellido);
}
```